# Added a Non-Nullable Field in Django After Creating Entries That Didn't Have That Field; Operational Error, No Such Field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my models, I added the class Source:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=False, blank=True, related_name='+')
    project= models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=False, blank=True, related_name='+')
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=False, blank=True, related_name='+')
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=False, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

For testing purposes, I added a few entries for posts in the Django admin page,
and then went back into my classes: Post, Profile, Department, Team, and Project, and added:

```
sourceID = models.ForeignKey('Source', default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=False)
```

for each class.

My problem is that when I go in the Django admin page to alter the database (i.e. create a new post) I get the following error:

[image]

Also, when I go to migrate my changes, I keep getting this warning:

`HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the LeadsConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.`

I would like to be able to create new entries in my database without the operational error. I've tried changing the null value = True, but this is counterintuitive and doesn't yield any change, surprisingly. I think the best way would be to delete the whole database, which I've tried to research and only found MYSql code solutions. What is the best course of action?

Comment: I would leave the field as `null=True` and `blank=True` and remove the default value which doesn't really make sense for a ForeignKey. Then make sure you've generated migrations with `./manage.py makemigrations` and then run them with `./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: @azundo If I do this, I get the error: The row in table 'leads_project' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: leads_project.sourceID_id contains a value 'sourceID_id' that does not have a corresponding value in leads_source.id.